# Recursive euclidean distance

Tags: recursion, lisp

I was tasked to write a recursive euclidean distance. I have been googling around but could not find any sample. I understand the function of euclidean distance and has no problem writing it in an iterative manner as shown below. Is there anyone who could advise me on how I should start for the recursive function? The requirement is the same as the iterative version. Thanks.

```
 (defun euclidean-distance-it (p q)  
  (cond
   ((or (null p) (null q)) nil) ;return nil if either list is null
   ((or (atom p) (atom q)) nil) ;return nil if either list is an atom
   ((or (null (cdr p)) (null (cdr q))) nil);return nil if either list contains less than two inputs

   ((or (not (null (car(cdr(cdr p))))) (not (null (car(cdr(cdr q)))))) nil) ;return nil if either list contains more than two inputs
   ((or (or (not (numberp (car p))) (not (numberp (cadr p)))) (or (not (numberp (car q))) (not (numberp (cadr q))))) nil);return nil if any of the four entires aren't numbers
   (T (sqrt (+ (expt (- (car p) (car q)) 2)
              (expt (- (cadr p) (cadr q)) 2)))))) ;Calculate the euclidean distance
```

Comment: Please provide more details: what are the inputs? the expected outputs? what did you try? Maybe you can show us the iterative version as a specification of the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I have added in the code for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time recursive algorithm for this would be sensible if the input are two vectors (represented by lists) of any dimension, not only 2 or 3. In this case this will compute the **square** of the distance:

```
(defun sq-euclid-distance (p q)
  (cond ((or (null p) (null q)) 0)
        (t (+ (expt (- (car p) (car q)) 2)
              (sq-euclid-distance (cdr p) (cdr q))))))
```

To get `SQRT` out of it you would need to make it into a auxiliary helper and make a driver computing the square root.

```
(defun euclid-distance (p q) (sqrt sq-euclid-distance p q))
```

PS. I am not checking if `p` and `q` are atoms, but they can be treated as 1-dimensional vectors. Returning `NIL` from the function that is expected to provide a numerical value is not a great idea.

Comment: Oh, thanks, #mobiuseng. Hope this would help those who are doing the recursive euclidean distance.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [this Haskell thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2vtjhb/recursive_euclidean_distance/), I think your task is more likely to compute the distance of n-dimensional vectors, i.e. `sqrt((x1-y1)^2 + ... + (xn-yn)^2)`.

In your example there is no iteration, you just access elements inside two lists. In other words: you assume that P and Q contains 2 elements and I think the question is to generalize this to N elements.

Moreover, you are doing many useless checks in order to return nil instead of letting errors be signaled. For example, if the lists do not contain numbers, you should probably *not* return nil.

I would rewrite your version like this:

```
(defun euclidean-distance-it (p q)
  (destructuring-bind (x1 x2) p
    (destructuring-bind (y1 y2) q
      (sqrt (+ (expt (- x1 y1) 2)
               (expt (- x2 y2) 2))))))
```

With a recursive version, I consider that `p` and `q` are two mathematical vectors, so that `p` contains different coordinates `(p1, ..., pn)`, which differs from your implementation where `p` contains all *x*'s and `q` all *y*'s.

So, you have to compute `(pi - qi)^2` for each for pair `(pi, qi)` of elements taken in parallel from `p` and `q`, sum the intermediate values and take the square root. With high-order functions, you don't even need to use recursion.

I won't spoil you the recursive answer, but here is a higher-order function version:

```
(defun distance (p q) 
  (sqrt
    (reduce #'+ 
      (map 'list
        (lambda (px qx) (expt (- px qx) 2)) 
        p q))))
```

And another one with `loop`:

```
(defun distance (p q)
  (sqrt (loop for px in p
              for qx in q
              sum (expt (- px qx) 2))))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a million. I truly understood what you mean. will rectify the changes.

Comment: Your third one would have the best output. The second one is not an iterative method. It uses the mapping way. The first one, on the other hand, I do not quite understand how the destructive-bind works. Would it be possible if you could share some light on that?

Comment: @Hero1134 The second one is indeed not iterative, it uses the [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) `map` and `reduce`. Contrary to the other answer I did not want to give you the exact solution to your question, but mainly guide you towards a solution. If you know reduce and map, it is possible to find out how to combine them in a single function. The first [destructuring-bind](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_destru.htm) binds  `x1` and `x2` to the two elements of the list `p`. If anything else than a two-element list is given, an error is reported.

Answer (score -2):

A late recursive variation with an optional argument switching between `sqrt` and `+`

```lisp
(defun distance (A B &optional (k 0))
  (if (zerop k)
      (sqrt (distance A B 1))
      (if (null A)
          0
          (+ (expt (- (car A) (car B)) 2) (distance (cdr A) (cdr B) 1)))))

(distance '(0 0 0) '(1 1 1)) ; => 1.7320508
```

Comment: This is a bad API. The procedure calls `(distance '(0 0 0) '(1 1 1))` vs `(distance '(0 0 0) '(1 1 1) 1)` vs `(distance '(0 0 0) '(1 1 1) 0)` vs `(distance '(0 0 0) '(1 1 1) nil)` are very unintuitive and error-prone. It would be better to use a keyword argument, e.g., `squared` so that you could call `(distance '(0 0 0) '(1 1 1))` to get the Euclidean distance vs `(distance '(0 0 0) '(1 1 1) :squared t)` to get the squared Euclidean distance.