# euclidean distance recursive function

Tags: lisp

I am to write a recursive function to find the euclidean distance given 2 list that is assumed to be of equal size always. The 2 list represents the vectors.

So below is my code but am missing the final step which is to square root the whole result after the last recursive call. Can I do so without introducing any variables?

```
(defun distance (l1 l2)
  (if (null l1) 
      0
      (+ (expt (- (first l1) (first l2)) 2)
     (distance (rest l1) (rest l2)))))
```

[image: Formula to euclidean distance I am implementing]

EDIT: I tried the answers from the suggested page and I get an error while testing it.
[image]

It says `The variable SQ-EUCLIDEAN-DISTANCE is unbound.`

```
(defun sq-euclidean-distance-rec (p q)
  (if (null p)
      0
      (+ (expt (- (first p) (first q)) 2)
     (sq-euclidean-distance-rec (rest p) (rest q)))))

(defun euclidean-distance-rec (p q) (sqrt sq-euclidean-distance p q))
```

Comment: Have you seen this question from a while ago: [Recursive euclidean distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125923/recursive-euclidean-distance?s=2%7C5.7578)

Comment: @jkiiski Thanks for the reference. But am facing some trouble still with the answer from it. Edit:Just some parenthesis problem. Changed to `(defun euclid-distance (p q) (sqrt (sq-euclid-distance p q)))`

Comment: Try changing `(sqrt sq-euclidean-distance p q)` to `(sqrt (sq-euclidean-distance-rec p q))`

Answer (score -2):

```
func distance(l1, l2):  
   if l1 == null || l2 == null  
      return 0  
   else  
      return sqrt((l1.first - l2.first) * (l1.first - l2.first) + distance(rest(l1), rest(l2)))
```

Comment: I don't know what language this is (almost Python), but it's definitely not Common Lisp or Scheme.

Comment: I don't mind if you give the solution to a homework question using another language, but here I think your answer is wrong: `sqrt(x1 + sqrt(x2 + ... (sqrt xn)))` is generally not equal to `sqrt(x1 + ... + xn)`, is it?

Comment: My answer is correct according to given formula.

Comment: @MajeedSiddiqui No. See [counter-example](http://pastebin.com/PhDUYB4Z)