# Compute euclidean distance with mapcar and apply

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to create a function that computes this using apply and mapcar.

I am stuck after using the first mapcar to get all the differences of p-q in a list. How do I square all the elements in the list and sum them up?

[image]

```
(defun euclidean-distance-map (p q)
  ;; get a list of differences of p - q
  (mapcar #'- p q))
```

Comment: See my previous answer, and replace `reduce` by `apply`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35127893/124319. Note that apply is limited by call-arguments-limit (http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm#call-arguments-limit). In practice, this constant is quite high.

Comment: ... but the other problem with `apply` is blowing the stack with too many arguments. You should use reduce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Higher Order Functions

If you are really required to stick to HOFs ([`reduce`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm) & [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm)), then here are a few options:

```
(defun euclidean-distance-map (p q)
  (let ((d (mapcar #'- p q))) ; get a list of differences of p & q
    (sqrt (reduce #'+ (mapcar #'* d d)))))

(defun euclidean-distance-map (p q)
  (sqrt (reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x) (* x x)) (mapcar #'- p q)))))

(defun euclidean-distance-map (p q)
  (sqrt (reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x y)
                              (let ((d (- x y)))
                                (* d d)))
                            p q))))
```

## `apply` vs `reduce`

Using [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm) instead of `reduce` is a *bad* idea (both because of [`call-arguments-limit`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm) and stylistically), but here you go:

```
(defun euclidean-distance-map (p q)
  (let ((d (mapcar #'- p q))) ; get a list of differences of p & q
    (sqrt (apply #'+ (mapcar #'* d d)))))

(defun euclidean-distance-map (p q)
  (sqrt (apply #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x) (* x x)) (mapcar #'- p q)))))

(defun euclidean-distance-map (p q)
  (sqrt (apply #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x y)
                             (let ((d (- x y)))
                               (* d d)))
                           p q))))
```

## Memory

Without the proverbial "sufficiently smart compiler", `mapcar` allocates storage which is immediately discarded.
This may not necessarily be a problem with a modern generational GC though.

## Iteration

Note that the iterative version using [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm) is no less clear:

```
(defun euclidean-distance-map (p q)
  (sqrt (loop for x in p
          and y in q
          for d = (- x y)
          sum (* d d))))
```

Lisp is a multi-paradigm language, you do not have to force yourself into a [specific](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Procrustean) framework.

Comment: `reduce` is definitely better than using `apply`

Answer (score 2):

coredump- actually answered it, but let's elaborate a bit. The problem can be split into the following tasks/steps (from the outermost to innermost):

1. Calculate square root, that's we know: `(sqrt .)`
2. To get `.`, we need to sum up squared differences. Here `apply` will do the work. We want `(+ a1 a2 a3 ...)`, the problem is we don't know how many of the items we want to add. Assuming these items can be put into the list, can do `(apply #'+ .)`. So, up to now we have `(sqrt (apply #'+ .))`.
3. Now we need to square the differences and put the result into the list. This can be done by `mapcar`: `(mapcar (lambda (x) (* x x)) .)`.
4. Finally, this differences need to come from `(mapcar #'- u v)`.

Overall,

```
(defun euclidian-distance (u v)
  (sqrt (apply #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x) (* x x)) (mapcar #'- u v)))))

> (euclidian-distance '(1 4 3) '(1 1 -1))
> 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation that uses higher-order functions and doesn't allocate a list for the differences:

```
(defun euclidian-distance (u v)
  (let ((sum 0.0))
    (mapc (lambda (x y)
            (let ((d (- x y)))
              (incf sum (* d d))))
          u
          v)
    (sqrt sum)))
```